# How to create dynamic Radio Button Group in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, radio-button

How can I create UI as per below with dynamic questions? currently I have hard coded Questions and options. But now requirement is to display dynamic questions. Options will be same like 1 to 5 radio buttons. But as per the Xamarin Forms controls list there is no Control like Radio button group. So how can I achieve this?

Currently My single question is added like :

```
<StackLayout Margin="0,15">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="How do you rate the quality of food on offer?" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="24"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Bad" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Text="4" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Text="5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="RbtnFoodQuality1" Source="radio_button.png" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10">
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RbtnFoodQuality1Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="RbtnFoodQuality2" Source="radio_button.png" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10">
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RbtnFoodQuality2Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="RbtnFoodQuality3" Source="radio_button.png" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10">
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RbtnFoodQuality3Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="RbtnFoodQuality4" Source="radio_button.png" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10">
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RbtnFoodQuality4Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="RbtnFoodQuality5" Source="radio_button.png" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10">
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RbtnFoodQuality5Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2" Text="Good" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontFamily="SF-UI-Text-Regular" FontSize="15"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
```

Now I have to handle Tapped event for every controls dynamically. Is this possible If I am using viewcell and bind it?

Or any other way to achieve this kind of functionality and UI?
[image: Feedback]

Comment: You could try to create a round bordered button, white background, no text?

Comment: It will look like this UI? And I can handle Click event of each buttons separately?

Comment: Honestly no idea if it will look like that, but it probably could look like that? And if it doesn't, why can't u just add the image dynamically?

Comment: I can Add Image but Issue with Tap gesture. How can I handle that?